# Accept Partial String input from user from a list

Tags: c

I’m trying to write a program where a user is to choose from a list of options, i.e.

```
Add: add a record
Printall: prints all records
Delete: delete a record
```

The user is to input the word add, printall, delete.  Where I’m stuck at is how do I allow my program to accept partial inputs. For example, a, ad, add will account for add

I’m using `fgets(user_input, 25, stdin)`

And I’m working with `if` statements. I’m trying to work with `strcmp` for comparison but can’t seem to get it to work.

I’m working in the C language environment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, for example to include a [mcve] of your attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: nevermind, it's been a while

Comment: We need you to post your code.  It is very hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: Can you show your code so that others can see what kind of problems you're facing?

Comment: Should we assume you intend this to operate case-insensitively?  ie: ```a, ad, add``` would each match ```Add```? and that you want to avoid ```regex```?

Comment: Hey Guys. Thanks for the help. I was actually able to figure it out. What I did is created char single character for each options allowed the user to input any of the following words within reason and just trimmed it to the first character. : )